# Block a row from reads whilst sp executes

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I have many .NET processes reading messages from an SQL Server 2008 DB table and processing them one at a time. I implement a simple SP to 'lock' the row that is being read by any one process, to avoid any two processes processing the same row.

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT @status = status FROM t WHERE t.id = @id
IF @status = 'L'
BEGIN
    -- Already locked by another process. Skip this
    RETURN 0
END
ELSE
    UPDATE t SET status = 'L' WHERE id = @id
    RETURN 1
END

COMMIT
```

However, this is flawed: sometimes a row gets 'locked' and processed twice. I suspect there is a concurrency problem: two processes reading the status before one updates it.

I think this could be resolved by implementing a read block somehow (i.e make the transaction block READs), but I am unsure how to do this. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot in advance

Ryan

Comment: I should add that the processes are separate .net processes, not a multi-threaded single execution, so this can't be solved at a c# programming level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using:

```
SELECT @status = status FROM t (UPDLOCK) WHERE t.id = @id
```

Refer to [this](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/advanced_sql_locking_p1.aspx) link for more details.

The thing you're missing is that a `SELECT` statement doesn't normally lock the row, so if one process has executed the `SELECT` but hasn't execute the `UPDATE` yet, but then another process comes along and executes the SELECT, then it's going to return the row back since you haven't locked it.

By using the `UPDLOCK`, you lock that row with your SELECT statement and prevent the other process from getting it back until the first process commits the transaction, which is the behavior you want.

**EDIT**
Of course, doing it with one statement as Martin suggests is the easiest way and you avoid having to deal with the locking issue at all.

Comment: +1 and in fact, with UPDLOCK it might be possible to devise a solution to lock the actual record you are processing without needing your manual locking strategy at all ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just replace the whole thing with

```
UPDATE t SET status = 'L' WHERE id = @id and status <> 'L'
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

This will avoid 2 table accesses and holding locks open for any longer than necessary.

Comment: I like your answer better, very nice!

Comment: Doh! Of course. Your answer is very elegant, thank you. However, I marked dcp's answer because it addressed the specific question I asked about row locking.